# Can I ask who has a beef with me and why?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Ok, so this meta post isn't so much a *"can* I ask" but a "I am asking". Though I suppose if meta isn't the place for such a thing then *"can* I ask" may be worth addressing.

I woke up this morning to find that someone had decided go through and downvote a bunch of my posts.

[image: downvotes and rep loss]

Normally I wouldn't care too much about getting downvoted - if I've made a mistake, someone disagrees, or I'm just plain wrong then that's fine, that's the system and community working - but in this case I feel as if someone's specifically targeting me and downvoting because they don't like me or perhaps they feel I've wronged them in some way.

At the end of the day the rep loss doesn't worry me, if you don't like me that's fine, I'm a big boy, I can live with that and move on, but I would like to try and address the issue and ask what I have seemly done to wrong a user, what I can do to improve in that area, and whether we can resolve the problem.

P.S. I'm not looking to get anyone in trouble, I just wish to resolve the issue before it potentially gets out of hand. If not then I'll just leave it and move on.

Comment: Looks like they mis-clicked on the lizard-monk one? Seriously, though, there are tools we have to look into this, and I'm figuring out how to use them right now =)

Comment: It's fixed! For me, at least.

Comment: @Miniman for me as well. Makes me feel a bit better knowing it wasn't just me then :,D.

Comment: See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) on the general stackexchange meta

Comment: Don't worry, besides the automated vote reversal  we've taken corrective action.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Though you can *ask* we can't answer due to votes being a private affair. **Never fear though**: all kinds of targeted-voting is detected by the system and, when the daily scripts run, it reverses the votes that are part of the offending vote pattern. Targeted voting is contrary to our goals of having votes reflect **content** quality, so though even targeted votes should remain private, we don't want them to continue *existing*.

Mods have some tools for inspecting voting patterns in aggregate, so we can also track down the culprit(s) manually when need be, such as to issue warnings or suspensions. We know who's responsible and will take appropriate action, if necessary.

Do let us know if the votes *aren't* reversed within 24 hours — in this case it seems unlikely that the system would miss it, but when it does the votes can be manually reversed by us contacting a Staff member.

Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Huh. I was unaware additional tools of these kinds were available to moderators. Should I have complained about 18 mo. ago when *every single one* of my answers—no matter how good—was downvoted almost immediately *when each answer was posted?* Could a mod have told me if I had a downvote stalker?

Comment: @HeyICanChan You could have, yes! (A flag on one of your downvoted posts is another way to get our attention with less fanfare, so there are options.) Likely the damage was automatically reversed the next day, so no harm done leaving it uninvestigated. The trouble in some cases is that it gets repeated, and then additional manual corrective measures become more helpful. But it's always fine to enquire.

Comment: (I think—given its current *13* upvotes—that it might be wise to incorporate our brief conversation here into the body of your answer!)